# Deleting Lines in text files c# using writeline

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, file, formatting

I am using this code so far - it writes the file but doesn't remove the line specified..  any help would be nice...

```
if (textBox1.Text == "")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please select a file");
}
else
{
    string line = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    string lineDelete = "hi";

    // Read the file and display it line by line.
    using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(textBox1.Text)){
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\test3.txt"))
    {     
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (String.Compare (line, lineDelete) == 0)
                continue;
            writer.WriteLine(line);
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Formatting Complete");

        // Suspend the screen.      
    }
}
```

Comment: _"It doesn't remove the line specified"_ is somewhat misleading, isn't it? You are writing lines from file1 to file2, lines which are `"hi"` will be omitted. So you are _ignoring_, not _deleting_ those lines. Is that what you want? Also, note that C# is case sensitive and that there also might be special characters which you can't see directly like white-spaces.

Comment: Yes I am omitting the word - as there is no delete from file function?

Comment: You're suggestion on white space validation solved it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"It doesn't remove the line specified"* is somewhat misleading, isn't it? You are writing lines from file1 to file2, lines which are `"hi"` will be omitted. So you are *ignoring*, not *deleting* those lines. Is that what you want? Also, note that C# is case sensitive and that there also might be special characters which you can't see directly like white-spaces.

So you could use `Trim` to remove white-spaces from the start and end of the line and you can use `String.Equals` to compare case-insensitive:

```
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    line = line.Trim();
    if(line.Equals(lineDelete, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
        continue;
    else
        writer.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I am only a beginner at C# so thanks for extra help.

Comment: Forgot to click the accept answer tick as well as the "This answer is useful" tally - Seems I am a forum noob as well as a C# noob :D.